# Why does this call the default constructor?

Tags: c++, syntax, most-vexing-parse

```
struct X
{
    X()    { std::cout << "X()\n";    }
    X(int) { std::cout << "X(int)\n"; }
};

const int answer = 42;

int main()
{
    X(answer);
}
```

I would have expected this to print either

- `X(int)`, because `X(answer);` could be interpreted as a cast from `int` to `X`, or
- nothing at all, because `X(answer);` could be interpreted as the declaration of a variable.

However, [it prints `X()`](http://ideone.com/QZDO1), and I have no idea why `X(answer);` would call the default constructor.

BONUS POINTS: What would I have to change to get a temporary instead of a variable declaration?

Comment: It does the same thing if you change `int answer` -> any other type.

Comment: I'm not sure what X(answer) is supposed to do, but if you create an instance initialized with an int, say X xx(answer), you'll get the X(int) print.

Comment: X((int)answer); however produces the correct result.

Comment: @JTA: Because that one can never be interpreted as a declaration, so it has to be a constructor invocation.

Comment: @JTA And finally, `X(int(answer));` doesn't print anything, because it's a function declaration :)

Comment: *nothing at all, because X(answer); could be interpreted as the declaration of a variable.* That declaration would also be a definition, and it triggers the execution of the default constructor... which in turn means that you answered your own question.

Comment: @David You're a bit late to the party, can I fetch you a drink? ;)

Comment: @FredOverflow: Make that a double expresso...

Comment: @David `double(expresso);` there you go, declared just for you ;)

Comment: @FredOverflow: I must need a *definition* to use it, because I am feeling no effect...

Answer (score 73, accepted):

> nothing at all, because X(answer); could be interpreted as the declaration of a variable.

Your answer is hidden in here. If you declare a variable, you invoke its default ctor (if non-POD and all that stuff).

On your edit: To get a temporary, you have a few options:

- [`(X(answer));`](http://liveworkspace.org/code/0d8f045cd715a27f126d26591098fc72)
- [`(X)answer;`](http://liveworkspace.org/code/87e18d40ffc27e49e0a07c9c05f1a775)
- [`static_cast<X>(answer)`](http://liveworkspace.org/code/9619098847d97f1809fb02adb219ab5d)
- [`X{answer};`](http://liveworkspace.org/code/c78c002e32755e18b3c03eaac6951e85) (C++11)
- [`[]{ return X(answer); }();`](http://liveworkspace.org/code/d3393ff9bb3f302c3e9facfba22f1c64) (C++11, may incur copy)
- [`void(), X(answer);`](http://liveworkspace.org/code/c803c5e68bf825d87e83cfa5294ee701)
- [`X((void(),answer));`](http://liveworkspace.org/code/ee2160ded0abd7dea87b2e743861af08)
- [`true ? X(answer) : X();`](http://liveworkspace.org/code/d29e7f10fceadca7ec24fef163b8afb6)
- [`if(X(answer), false){}`](http://liveworkspace.org/code/6eff0bb82d0c27334322ce22761e3ea2)
- [`for(;X(answer), false;);`](http://liveworkspace.org/code/160fa87d472ebe74c3f5c2b44d7ff706)
- [`X(+answer);`](http://liveworkspace.org/code/6914b3dbc2b6821e5bc51467dab97420)

Comment: The `static_cast<X>(answer)` feels the "most C++" answer -- it's even recommended by an old [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.2/gcc/Volatiles.html) as a way to force an rvalue.

Comment: Won't the brace initializer also maybe incur a copy?

Comment: @rubenvb: Why would it? It's just a fancy new way of saying `X(answer)` and guarantees a ctor call.

Comment: @Xeo: because brace initializer syntax takes its arguments by value? (<- note the question mark)

Comment: @rubenvb: Oh, I didn't mean that the `answer` is copied, I meant when the `X` is returned from inside the lambda.

Comment: @KerrekSB But surely only before C++11, no? Now, the canonical answer will be `X{answer}`.

Comment: Can anybody please explain
how `X(answer)` is equivalent to `X answer` ?

Comment: @SAM: Because the standard says so. As Kerrek's answer says, the parens are optional.

Comment: @Xeo Common man! Just tell me how do you know every little detail about c++? I'm not asking about just this question but I've seen your other answers too. I mean, just look at`void(), X(answer);` How on earth did you find that out?!?! Also what do you refer for C++? I read TC++PL (3rd & 4th edition). Also how did you learned C++11 in such a short time?

Comment: @Xeo And how many years of programming experience did you require to get to this stage?

Comment: @SAM: I recommend joining me in the Lounge chat room (check my profile), since this is getting off-topic here. :)

Answer (score 67):

The parentheses are optional. What you said is identical to `X answer;`, and it's a declaration statement.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to declare a variable of the type X, you should do it this way:

```
X y(answer);
```

Comment: He did not ask how to make it call the `X(int)` ctor.

Comment: Yeah but I have a small feeling that it was the thing he ment to do :)

Comment: @WouterH: Actually, knowing Fred, it's unlikely. He's one of those folks who like to explore the dark corners of the C++ Standard and try and understand it. In a certain RPG he would have lost all his sanity points already ;)