# Conditional overloading with trailing-return-type possible?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, trailing-return-type

Suppose you attempt to do the following:

```
template</* args */>
typename std::enable_if< /*conditional*/ , /*type*/ >::type
static auto hope( /*args*/) -> decltype( /*return expr*/ )
{
}
```

Is it possible to combine conditional inclusion/overloading (`std::enable_if`) with trailing-return-type (`auto ... -> decltype()`)?

I would not be interesting in solutions using the preprocessor. I can always do things like

```
#define RET(t) --> decltype(t) { return t; }
```

and extend it to take also the whole conditional. Instead I am interested if the language supports it without using another trait for the return type, i.e. `ReturnType<A,B>::type_t` or whatever is used in the function body.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The *trailing-return-type* isn't much different from the normal return type, except that it's specified after the parameter list and cv-/ref-qualifiers. Also, it doesn't necessarily need `decltype`, a normal type is fine too:

```
auto answer() -> int{ return 42; }
```

So by now you should see what the answer to your question is:

```
template<class T>
using Apply = typename T::type; // I don't like to spell this out

template</* args */>
static auto hope( /*args*/)
    -> Apply<std::enable_if</* condition */, decltype( /*return expr*/ )>>
{
}
```

Though I personally prefer using just `decltype` and expression SFINAE, as long as the condition can be expressed as an expression (e.g., can you invoke a function on an object of a certain type):

```
template<class T>
static auto hope(T const& arg)
  -> decltype(arg.foo(), void())
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! So, your second case would not support a conditional `std::is_base_of<>::value`, right? In this case, one would go for the first case.

Comment: @Frank: Yeah, `is_base_of` is rather complicated to easily test. You can easily check if a certain type is convertible to another type (`decltype(T2(obj_of_T1))` for explicit conversion), but you can't determine if the class just has a conversion operator / ctor or if it's a base class, that needs some additional blackbox magic (or compiler support).

Comment: Uhm... too lazy to look it up, but I don't think you can use `enable_if` on a non-templated function (even if it is a member of a template).

Comment: @David: Yeah, I'll add that and add the templates tag to the question; SFINAE never goes without templates after all.

Comment: @KennyTM: [`void(), X(answer); // force ctor call`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11691101/500104). ;)

Answer (score 2):

I can only assume that your original pseudo code is a function template, or otherwise SFINAE would not work altogether. Now if it is a template function, you can use an extra template argument that is defaulted and use SFINAE on that argument:

```
template <typename T, typename _ = typename std::enable_if< trait<T>::value >::type >
static auto function( T arg ) -> decltype( expression ) {
   // ...
}
```

I prefer this as it limits the use of SFINAE to the `template` clause and leaves a cleaner function signature. This is one of my favorite *under-the-radar* new features of C++11.

Comment: Even better: [`template<class T, EnableIf<trait<T>,int>...>`](http://rmartinho.github.com/2012/06/01/almost-static-if.html).

Comment: Nice thing! Yes, I meant a function template. Thanks for the edit, @Xeo.