# Overload resolution and universal reference parameters

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code works and the overloads are found as expected:

```
struct HasBuzz
{
    void buzz() const {}
};

struct NoBuzz {};

template <typename T>
void foo(T const& t)
{
    t.buzz();
}

void foo(NoBuzz const&){}

int main()
{
    foo(HasBuzz{});
    foo(NoBuzz{});
}
```

However, if I replace the first overload with a "universal reference" version then it no longer works. The correct overload is not found for `NoBuzz`.

```
struct HasBuzz
{
    void buzz() const {}
};

struct NoBuzz {};

template <typename T>
void foo(T&& t)
{
    t.buzz();
}

void foo(NoBuzz const&){}

int main()
{
    foo(HasBuzz{});
    foo(NoBuzz{}); // error: NoBuzz has no member function buzz
}
```

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: Overload resolution has nothing to do with "the guts" of the function.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Ah, yeah I misinterpreted the reason for the overload choice in the first case. But the question still remains.

Comment: `void foo(T&& t)` is a better match than binding the temporary to a const reference `void foo(NoBuzz const&)`, so the compiler will use the rvalue reference function. I had kind of a similar question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029213/overloading-reference-vs-const-reference

Comment: I think the answer to your underlying question is `std::enable_if` ( http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if ).

Answer (score 9):

**Simple solution**

Add an overload that is callable with an *rvalue* of type NoBuzz.

```
void foo(NoBuzz const&){ }; 
void foo(NoBuzz&&)     { }; // overload for rvalues
```

<sup>**Note**: Depending on your actual use case this might not be enough, because if you pass a non-const *lvalue* type *NoBuzz* to `foo` you'd still instantiate the template, since the two `NoBuzz` overloads doesn't match. 

 At the end of this post is a more complex, but certainly cleaner, solution.</sup>

---

**Explanation**

```
 template<class T>
 void foo (T&&);            // (A)
 void foo (NoBuzz const&);  // (B)
```

The problem with your snippet is that your template *(A)* can be instantiated in such a way that it's a better match than your overload *(B)*.

When the compiler sees that you are trying to call a function named *foo* with an argument which is an *rvalue* of type `NoBuzz`, it will look for all functions named *foo* taking one argument where a `NoBuzz` would fit.

Let's say it starts of with your template *(A)*, here it sees that `T&&` is deducable to any reference type (both *lvalue*, and *rvalue*), since we are passing an *rvalue* `T = NoBuzz`.

With `T = NoBuzz` the instantiated template would be semantically equivalent to:

```
void foo (NoBuzz&&); // (C), instantiated overload of template (A)
```

It will then continue to your overload *(B)*. This overload accepts a *const lvalue reference*, which can bind to both lvalues and rvalues; but our previous template instantiation *(C)* can only bind to *rvalues*.

Since *(C)* is a better match than *(B)*, binding rvalues to `T&&` is prefered over `U const&`, that overload is selected and you get the behavior you describe in your post.

---

**Advanced solution**

We can use a technique called [*SFINAE*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) to conditionally make it impossible to call the template if the type passed doesn't implement `.buzz ()`.

```
template <typename T>
auto foo(T&& t) -> decltype (t.buzz ())
{
  return t.buzz();
}
```

The above solution uses a lot of new features of *C++11*, detailed information is available here:

- [wikipedia.org - C++11 - `auto`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Type_inference)
- [wikipedia.org - decltype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype)
- [Conditional overloading with trailing-return-type possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11866291/1090079)

Answer (score 2):

refp's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24043156/241631) explains the behavior you're seeing, and offers a possible solution. Another option is to ensure the `foo` function template does not make it into the candidate set for overload resolution unless `T` has a member function named `buzz()`.

```
template <typename T>
auto foo(T&& t)
    -> decltype((void)(t.buzz()), void())
{
    t.buzz();
}
```

After making this change the `foo(NoBuzz const&)` overload will be selected when you pass it an instance of `NoBuzz`. [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f47faed4a0fe6031)

A detailed explanation of what's going on in the `decltype` expression in the trailing return type can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23988669/241631). The only thing I've done differently here is instead of using three subexpressions, with the middle one being `void()` to prevent a user defined `operator,` from being selected, I've cast the result of the first expression to `void`; the intent and result are identical in both cases.

Comment: *"instead of using a second subexpression `void()`"* Well you *do* use a `, void()` -- isn't that redundant with the cast?

Comment: @dyp :) That *second subexpression* refers to the explanation in the linked answer. I guess you are right about the redundancy in this case since the return type is also `void`, but I'm going to leave that in there so that the linked explanation still makes sense.