# Weird compiler decision

Tags: c++, g++

I've got the following code:

```
enum nums {
  a
};

class cls {
public:
  cls( nums );
};

void function()
{
  cls( a );
}
```

When I try to compile it with gcc, I get the following error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘void function()’:
test.cpp:12:10: error: no matching function for call to ‘cls::cls()’
test.cpp:12:10: note: candidates are:
test.cpp:7:3: note: cls::cls(nums)
test.cpp:7:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:5:7: note: cls::cls(const cls&)
test.cpp:5:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

If I replace the function with this:

```
void function()
{
  cls name( a );
}
```

then everything works. It also works if I use a constructor with two arguments. It does not work if I add "explicit" to the constructor.

I get that gcc is somehow parsing this as defining a variable of type "cls" with the name "a", but I am not familiar with such a syntax for defining variables. To my eyes, this is a statement defining an anonymous temporary variable of type cls, passing "a" is the parameter.

Compiled with gcc 4.6.3.

Any insights?

Thanks,
Shachar

Comment: Err... what do you imagine `cls(a);` *should* do?!

Comment: says so in the question - create a temporary object of type "Cls".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The parentheses are optional. So `cls (a);` is the same as `cls a;`, which declares an object  `a` of type `cls` and default-initializes it (which fails because there is no matching constructor).

To just create a temporary value that expires at the end of the expression, you can say `cls { a };` in C++11, or `(cls(a));` (or any number of more arcane constructs, like `void(0), cls(a);`).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11691101/596781) for more ideas.

Comment: That resembles "most vexing parse"

Comment: @gx_: Both the MVP and the OP's problem are based on statements being function declarations rather than expression-statements if there's an ambiguity.

Comment: What is the use of those parentheses?

Comment: @johnchen902: The parenthesized statement can only be interpreted in one way (namely as an expression).

Comment: @KerrekSB I meant the parentheses in `cls (a);`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: but it is not interpreted as an expression. It is interpreted as a variable definition

Comment: @johnchen902: Oh. Those are optional. Like in `cls((((a))))`.

Comment: @KerrekSB "(...) statements being _declarations_ rather than expression-statements if there's an ambiguity", not always _function_ declarations; that's why I said "resembles", because the "typical" MVP implies an unwanted function declaration and this question implies an unwanted _variable_ declaration. (So my comment was not a criticism, just a comment :))

Comment: @KerrekSB Is there a direct reason that those parentheses are *allowed*?

Comment: @johnchen902: You sometimes *have* to be able to group type name parts explicitly, so this is a generally useful feature, like in `(int *)[10]`, as opposed to `int * [10]`.

Comment: @KerrekSB Rather `int (*p)[10]` (ptr-to-array) vs `int* a[10]` (array of ptrs) ("`(int *)[10]`" is not valid syntax)

Comment: @gx_: Perhaps a more immediate example: `new int (*)[10]` is not valid syntax, but `new (int (*)[10])` is.

Answer (score 10):

Another example of the most embarassing parse problem.  The
line:

```
cls( a );
```

declares a local variable named `a` of type `cls`, which is (or
should be) initialized by calling the default constructor.
Which doesn't exist, whence the error message.

If you really want to construct a temporary object which will be
destructed immediately after, you can remove the ambiguity by
putting the entire expression in parentheses:

```
(cls( a ));
```

A definition cannot occur in parentheses; an expression can.